# System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' does not contain a definition for 'First' and no extension method 'First' accepting a first argument of

Tags: linq

I am trying to change some custommessage encoder Using this blog

```
http://www.falconwebtech.com/post/2010/05/24/WCF-Interoperability-and-Extensibility-Part-Two.aspx
```

Here the author uses a extension method

```
 xmlMessage.Descendants(sec + "Security").First().Add(samlXml);
```

What namespace do I use for this .First
This is the error I am getting

'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'First' and no extension method 'First' accepting a first argument of 
  type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' 
  could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have the following namespaces included

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.Security.Cryptography.Xml;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security;
using System.ServiceModel.Security;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens;
```

I could've done my research but I am taking the easy way

Thank you

Comment: "I could've done my research but I am taking the easy way" Your time is more valuable than ours, right?

Comment: I'm not sure its the easy way... The time taken to find the answer should have been less than the time taken to write the question. I'll give you a hint. First hit on google for "linq first" is the msdn page for the method you want. That page tells you what the namespace is.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`System.Linq` is the one you're after.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.first.aspx

Comment: I wish VisualStudio would suggest including that missing `using`... Thx Chris!